# Utilizing p5.js/processing for data visualization on a GeoTIFF? How to plot Lon/Lat coordinates in web mercator?

Tags: javascript, processing, gis, data-visualization, p5.js

I work on a database collecting archaeological sites. A goal of our project is to make the data accessible on the web. I would like to plot them on a GeoTIFF to show their distribution and change over time. I further want to calculate Delaunay triangulations and a heatmap which you could display as an overlay. Its important to me to visualize the change over time as an animation. I choose p5.js/processing because I'm not a very skilled programmer (some R, NetLogo and Processsing). i think it will fit the task especially regarding the animation. Before I get into more detail my first question is:

Is this a wise choice of tools? Would you recommend other tools?

If you think my choice is vital here is my second question:

I came across Daniel Shiffmans tutorial on visualizing earthquake data in p5.js and this comes close to what I would do:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiYdOwOrGyc

The code is here:
https://github.com/CodingTrain/Rainbow-Code/blob/master/CodingChallenges/CC_57_Earthquake_Viz/sketch.js

In the above example he relies on mapbox.js. I would prefer to use a custom build GeoTiff from our project and avoid mapbox since its not 100% free. But how do I get his code to work with a custom GeoTiff as basemap? I can set his variables "clon" and "clat" to my custom Tiff center point but the coordinates did not get transformed right. I think the Problem is the in the zoom level aka "zoom". But how to determine the Zoom for my custom map? I did not find any other implementation of web mercator projection in p5.js nor processing. Or do i get the math beyond projection wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very proficient with p5.js, but I have a good experience using d3.js for various dataviz tasks, including crunching geodata. So my suggestion would be to use best of both worlds — use p5.js for rendering and d3.js for data manipulation. In your case, it seems like you will need a simple reprojection (LonLat to Mercator).

To reiterate:

1. Use d3.js to project data from whatever projection it is (LonLat) into projection that p5.js is using (Mercator)
2. Render projected data in p5.js

Quick googling landed me [this guide on d3 + p5 integration](http://sciutoalex.github.io/p5-D3-cookbook/)

On the d3 side, there is an [API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#geographies-d3-geo)

And here is a [good example of GeoTIFF reading/rendering](http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/263b324083ece278e966686d7dba700f) in d3.js. Ok, here is [one more](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/83c0be21dba7602ee14982b020b12f51).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I will see them through!